# Get posts that have a category name begin by a term

Tags: php, wordpress

If I use WP_Query class for example :

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff,news' );
```

I will get posts that have these categories, using category slug, but how can I get posts that have a category name begin by a term for example :

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=s%' );
```

I wish I explain well my question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in your theme functions.php like:

```
<?php

/**
* @ $taxonomy = the taxonomy name 
* @ $search = the string you are searching
* @ return array of term names
*/
function getDesiredTerms($taxonomy, $search) {

    $result = get_terms(
        $taxonomy, 
        array(
            'hide_empty'    => false, // get them all           
            'fields'        => 'names', // get only the term names  
            'name__like'    => $search // Note: This was changed in WordPress 3.7, when previously name__like matched terms that begin with the string.
            )
        );
    return $result;

}
```

Be aware of what Wordpress version you are using.

More details in the Codex at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms. 
Look for the 'name__like' parameter

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I needed to have a search that included fuzzy matches from the function get_terms.  I was originally using `name__like` to help refine search results, but ended up getting all of the terms and used `similar_text()` to compare the search input vs. the term names.

Below is the function I ended up using.  Hope it helps someone:

```
$search_text = "WHATEVER YOUR SEARCH INPUT IS";

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => array( 'product_cat' ), // taxonomy name
    'orderby'       => 'id', 
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => false,
    'fields'        => 'all'
    //'name__like'    => $search_text  //I TOOK THIS PART OUT
); 
$terms = get_terms( $args );

//FILTER FUZZY MATCHING
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $item = similar_text($search_text, $term->name, $percentage);
    if($percentage >= 50) :
        echo $term->name . ' - ' . $percentage . '<br />';
    endif; 
}
```

You can modify the percentage threshold to yield the results you want.  In my case, this worked great for me. It may not work very well for others in certain cases.